# Uploading a yii project on a ftp

Tags: php, yii, ftp, connection

I'm having a trouble with the directory of the files. I've tried several addresses and I can't seem to put the right one. I'm using Filezilla as my ftp

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

I keep getting this error

```
Warning: require_once(/kristian/dev/framework/yii.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /kristian/dev/system/index.php on line 12
```

What must be the right address/directory?

The FTP
http://i40.tinypic.com/2qc2jc3.jpg

Comment: Your framework exist in correct path?

Comment: Yes. I've modified it $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/dev/framework/yii.php';

Comment: Where is your YII core folder?

Comment: Which errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

if you install apache2, you can find the dir:/var/www/.
you must move framework and system to /var/www/.
you can try it.